# Tutorials on embedded programing using Zynq 7020 with ARM processor

Tags: embedded, programming, xilinx, hardware, tutorial

Just as the question states. I have been having trouble being able to just test out the programming side of the ARM processor on the TE0720 board. I have been searching online for how to setup the board, and get into some SDK where I can program the thing, but everytime I try something, I run into errors (which I cannot find any fixes for).

I have all of the Xilinx tools/SDK's and Vivado downloaded, but I just need some sort of tutorial to help me get started working with these things. At this point I am just trying to run a simple "hello world" or blinking LED test code. Are there any tutorials that are specifically for what I am trying to do, or at least to bring the board to life?

Answer (score 2):

Call your Avnet Rep and ask for the Speedway Introduction to Zynq-7000™ All Programmable SoC Featuring ISE WebPACK 14 class material. It will show you how to set-up the hello world for the ZED board using the Xilinx Tool Chain.